# Install new APK version of my Android app from SD card

Tags: android, version, apk, updates, uninstallation

I recently fixed a bug in a demo version of my app. It's not out on the store yet, we're still testing.

The phone doesn't like it however : it tells me there's already an APK called that. That's true, but why doesn't it suggest to just replace it ?

And in the "Apps" settings screen, "Force quit" and "Uninstall" are greyed out - unclickable, can't do that for my app. Yes, I did quit my app, and the background service associated with it. Because yes, my app does require the following permissions :

- Full Internet access
- System tools : prevent sleeping, disable key lock, auto-start on boot
- Hardware controls : audio volume
- Storage : SD card

Any clues or things to do/check before uninstalling ? This other (empty) app that's also installed (an app I made when I was discovering Android for testing purposes) was uninstalled fine ...

Thanks in advance,

Charles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possible causes I know of for it not offering to replace it:

- You changed the package name, but you are using the same file name
  for the APK.
- You signed the package with a different keystore or key. Note that when clicking Run in Eclipse, it uses a debug keystore rather than the one you would use when exporting it for the store.

I'm not sure why it would disallow force quitting and uninstall. Maybe you just need to wait a few more seconds for that screen to finish loading, and the buttons will become active.

You can try opening a console and using `adb uninstall com.yourpackagename` to uninstall the old version, and see if it gives you any errors.

Comment: Thanks for the help, will try. See edit though, there are fresher news.

Comment: Maybe it's saved on the SD card, but the SD card is mounted because you're connected to your computer? Try disconnecting from a computer and then uninstalling it.

Comment: Re package name, nope, still the same, only the version number was updated.
Re signing, I didn't sign anything that I know of, I just used the auto-generated APK from the bin folder - is it automatically signed ?

Comment: Btw where do I find a console on the phone ?

Comment: The adb console is launched from your computer where your android sdk is installed, either in the tools/ folder or the platform-tools/ folder.

Comment: Yes, it's auto-signed with a debug key when you are just compiling it from Eclipse.

Comment: Ok. So that's why it can't be replaced. THe real story is that I'm just  fixing this app but someone else did it, and probably used a different key indeed.
But now, that doesn't explain why the originally buggy app can't be uninstalled ! And by the way, I may well use a console when my simulators are running or anything, but my client clearly cannot on his phone if it requires the ADB, he's no tech guy ... What else could he do to rid himself of this old app version ?

Answer (score 0):

Got it !

First of all, see Tenfour's answer on impossible replacement. As for  impossible uninstallation :

The "Lock Screen" permission makes my app a Device Administrator. And Device Admins can't be uninstalled !

The app can be downgraded in Settings -> Security -> Device Admins.

That's all folks ! Thanks for the help.